# error: failed to push some refs to (URL) because a file exceeds file size limit Event if the file it No longer exists

Tags: git, file, github, command-line, filesize

Today I'm having some problems while pushing my project into GitHub, I had a 7z file That measures more than 100mb, I deleted it and still failed to push because of it, It doesn't even exist in the actual folder how can I fix that?

I've tried a lot of things such as "reinit" the repository but it still doesn't work, I also tried to use a different file with the same name and file extension with lower size, (text file inside a 7Zip file) but it still doesn't work, Also I tried to delete `.git/hooks/pre-push` and deleted all inside `.git/hooks/` folder but still doesn't What can I do?

Edit 1: The `git status` command the output shows this

```
    On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 11 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Edit 2: I also tried the `git reset --soft HEAD~1` command, committed the changes, and then pushing them but still doesn't work the file doesn't exist and still detects the same file.

Edit 3: the file that is causing that is `example_mods\vs-bloodiey\sourcefiles\assets.7z` it measures more than 100mb but I already deleted it and still can't push because of it

Sorry for not putting this information earlier I was busy until now

Comment: What is the output of `git status`? Add this important information by editing your original post. No comment

Comment: how can I see that

Comment: In the file still present in the history between your HEAD and your tracking location?

Comment: yes there was a track and a lot of commits behind, I used `git reset --soft HEAD~11` instead of `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of Gilles Quénot and NoDataFound about the `git status` command, In the track, I saw a lot of commits behind so I used the command `git reset --soft` but instead of `HEAD~1` I used `HEAD~(number of commits ahead)` for example in my case was 11 so  used `HEAD~11` I pulled the changes and that solved my problem thank you.